# Make Windows Installer ignore a running process

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

Using Installshield 2010 and Basic MSI project.

I have an exe that was previously installed by my installer.  That exe needs to be running during an installer upgrade.  Is there a way to guarantee that the installer won't try shutdown the process?   Basically, I would like the behavior to be : If file doesn't exist, lay it down, otherwise ignore it.

I have made the exe a key file in a component and set it 'Never Overwrite' to true.  Should this give me my desired behavior ?

Comment: It would be great if you can explain why the EXE file must be in use? It sounds like a very peculiar deployment strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never Overwrite will be used by future installers to determine if the file will be overwritten or not by other MSI packages. Basically, this attribute should have been set for the installed EXE.

A good approach is to use a [file search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371853%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determine if the EXE exists. The search property can then be used to condition the new component.

Windows Installer doesn't automatically close applications, but it does show a FilesInUse dialog which offers this option to the user.

Comment: So basically I was trying to disable showing the FilesInUse dialog to the user for that particular application.  Possible ?

Comment: FilesInUse is not shown only if there are no running applications for which files need to be replaced. So you can try the approach I suggested to see if it's still shown when the EXE condition is not met. If this doesn't work, the only solution would be to manually handle the file instead of letting Windows Installer handle it (store it somewhere, extract it during install etc).

Comment: Depending on your upgrade model, you might also need to mark the file as Permanent so the uninstallation doesn't try to remove it.